# How to set text to a TextBlock from a backgroundworker

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, backgroundworker

I want to show in realtime (updating every 1s for example) some temperatures to my program's interface.

To do this I believe I'm going to need to run some code in a background worker so the main program doesn't get blocked. My question here is if it's possible to set the text of a `TextBlock` from a background worker and if yes, how to do it.

This is the basic idea:

```
backgroundworker
{
     while(true)
     {
           //reading and updating temperatures
           //.....
     }
}
```

Comment: you could take the Event approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` has built in support for reporting the current progress of the work, which sounds like it's exactly what you're doing:

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

worker.DoWork += (s, args) =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);//placehodler for real work
        worker.ReportProgress(0, "Still working");
    }
};

worker.ProgressChanged += (s, args) =>
{
    textBox1.Text = args.UserState as string;
};

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

By leveraging the built in support you allow the background worker to handle marshaling to the UI thread.  (It will ensure that all of the events besides `DoWork` run in the UI thread.)

This also has the advantage of separating the UI logic from the business logic, rather than embedding code for manipulating the UI all throughout code doing business work.